# Profiling memory usage of all variables during runtime in C# app

Tags: c#, variables, memory, profiling, runtime

To reduce the memory footprint in my C# app to below the limit (around 1-2GB), I would love to see a list of all variables in realtime (during runtime), along with how much memory they eat up (and maybe even the contents).

From what I can see, this seemingly simple request seems to have escaped the attention of the memory profilers out there. .NET Memory Profiler for instance shows the memory for each given type (e.g. Int32[] or String), but doesn't seem to allow finer granularity to show the memory for each named variable.

Although I haven't tried dotTrace or ANTS Memory Profiler, scanning the FAQ, videos and screenshots draws a blank too.

Apart from my own variables, the desired profiler would probably include 'overhead' memory usage typical for any .NET app, though to me, that's less important.

Is there any program (preferably free or under $100) which can do this?

------------- EDIT

For variables which reference each other (as shown by Jon Skeet), or for variables passed by reference to a method, the profiler could maybe either group them to show that they're really the same object (and therefore 'share' the same memory), or just show the original variable name and omit the references.

Answer (score 4):

> but doesn't seem to allow finer granularity to show the memory for each named variable.

That's probably because it doesn't make much sense. Variables themselves don't generally take up much memory - it's *objects* which take up memory, and variables just prevent those objects from being garbage collected.

So for example, consider the following code:

```
byte[] array = new byte[1024 * 1024]; // 1MB
byte[] array2 = array;
byte[] array3 = array;
```

Here we have three variables, all referring to the same array. How much memory would your desired tool show each of them taking? 1MB, because each one refers to a 1MB array? That would be confusing, as the total memory shown would be 3MB despite only 1MB actually being used. 0.3333MB? Surely more confusing. 1MB? Sort of accurate, but unhelpful.

You should concentrate on which *objects* stay alive longer than you want them to, then work out what's keeping those objects alive.

Usually, if a "seemingly simple request" seems to have "escaped the attention" of people who specialize in the area, it's because it's *not* a simple request after all.

Comment: I rarely reference variables to other variables like you have shown here, but maybe I should rename 'variable' to 'object' in light of what you've said here. I do want the names though as they will appear in my code, and then I can quickly navigate to them. Knowing Int32[] takes up say 1GB is less help - I'd like to know the variable name in the code. I suppose in your example, the profiler could group up references like that. It's not unsurmountable.

Comment: @DanW: Objects don't *have* names - that's the point. I don't know how feasible it would be to keep track of the name of every variable which "currently" holds a reference to an object...

Comment: Right. Yeah, it'd have to be the names of the variables. Surely I can't be the only one to think of or want this? It'd be ideal to see a list of all the var names, at least in my case.

Comment: By the way, just to clarify, it doesn't have to record every variable name that exists, just the 'original' one. For example, if a variable is passed by reference to a method, then it wouldn't bother showing that name too (which would be the same memory of course), just the original name. Does that make more sense now?